# Call to a member function update() on integer when I trying to change state - laravel

Tags: php, laravel, integer

I'm trying to change the value from my "state" field on my meo table, this is my code

```
public function startStop($id)
    {
        $DigestReport = Meo::select('state')->where('id', '=', $id)->first()->state;
        if ($DigestReport < 1){
            $DigestReport = 1;
        } else {
        $DigestReport = 0;}
        $DigestReport->update();
    }
```

but I get this

> Call to a member function update() on integer

I have debugged and everything goes well until the last line when I want to update that field

note: In my DB the field "state" is "integer"

Comment: it would be `$DigestReport->save();`

Comment: @sta If I do that, I get this Error
Call to a member function save() on integer

Comment: @sta I want to update just one field on my table, the "state" field

Comment: DigestReport is an integer from your select and set.. you cant call update() there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should update the record in DB not the result:

```
$DigestReport = Meo::select('state')->where('id', '=', $id)->first()->state;
        if ($DigestReport < 1){
            $DigestReport = 1;
        } else {
        $DigestReport = 0;}
       Meo::where('id', '=', $id)->update(['state'=>$DigestReport]);
```

Comment: Please wait, the page says I should wait a couple of minutes